# Delete CSV row for matching record in awk

Tags: csv, awk

My csv file looks like:

```
data,code,name
2020-02-24,069,AA
2020-02-24,066,BB
2020-02-24,068,CC
2020-02-24,067,DD
2020-02-24,979,Updating
```

I would like to delete rows which have "Updating" in field `name`

So the output should be like:

```
data,code,name
2020-02-24,069,AA
2020-02-24,066,BB
2020-02-24,068,CC
2020-02-24,067,DD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this command and you will get the result you requested:

`awk -F, '{ if($3 != "Updating") print $0;}' test    //test is your file name`

**before:**

```
cat test
data,code,name
2020-02-24,069,AA
2020-02-24,066,BB
2020-02-24,068,CC
2020-02-24,067,DD
2020-02-24,979,Updating
```

**After:**

```
data,code,name
2020-02-24,069,AA
2020-02-24,066,BB
2020-02-24,068,CC
2020-02-24,067,DD
```

**so basically awk will look for the lines doesn't have Updating word in it and print them out.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, particularly the Code and Preformatted Text section

Comment: `'{ if($3 != "Updating") print $0;}'` can be written as just `'$3 != "Updating"'`.